# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dlib'

Tags: python, c++, dlib

I build dlib on Ubuntu16.04 by following step:

```
cd examples
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build . --config Release
```

and also compiled the dlib python completely

```
cd ../..
python setup.py install
```

But now I only can import dlib at the /dlib-19.17 path
if not , always got the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dlib'
I think it is the problem with environment variables

How can I fix it

Comment: After executing `cmake --build . --config Release` did you remember to do `sudo make install` and so on? There is a nice tutorial [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-dlib-on-ubuntu/) with all the shell commands and everything.

Comment: Well , I removed all and do this tutorial , Problems didn’t fix

Comment: Problems fixed , thanks a lot